# React Boilerplate cannot be run with "npm run start"

Tags: react-boilerplate

After a fresh checkout of [react-boilerplate](http://reactboilerplate.com) and running

```
npm run setup
```

and

```
npm run start
```

It stops with an error message similar to this:

```
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.4.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@3.4.0 start script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was (in my case) very simple:

**Make sure no other react boilerplate dev server is running on the same ports.**

I halted the other running one and it worked.

HTH and spare someone an hour of looking through actual npm/react-boilerplate issues.